# How to link main.rs to lib.rs dynamically?

Tags: rust

I have a crate with both `src/lib.rs` and `src/main.rs`.

`main.rs` is just using `extern crate programname` (which is `lib.rs`) and uses certain functions from `lib.rs` and it's submodules.

The [documentation on linking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/advanced-linking.html#static-linking) says:

> Pure-Rust dependencies are statically linked by default so you can use created binaries and libraries without installing Rust everywhere.

How can I change this behavior so a binary created from `main.rs` will be dynamically linked to library produced by `lib.rs`?

I've added the following to `Cargo.toml`

```
[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["dylib"]

[[bin]]
name = "programname"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

But it does not compile and gives me errors like:

```
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `std` only shows up once
help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away
```

If I add "rlib" to `lib` section, it compiles, but the binary is not linked against `libprogramname.so`

Comment: have you tried splitting the lib into another crate? maybe it's a bug due to the lib and bin being in the same crate?

Comment: If I move main.rs to another package, binary gets linked against library if I build it like `cargo rustc --release -j 5 -- -C prefer-dynamic`, thanks! One question still remains, is it possible to manipulate how does an executable looks for this library? I saw for example some programs linked using a relative path like `../lib64/libwine.so` in PlayOnLinux wine builds

Comment: That's a really good question, I suggest you post it as a separate question, but I fear Rust has no solution yet.

Comment: you can also try adding the crate-type field to the binary, as apparently the field is ignored when the crate is only a dependency.

Comment: Has anyone used this and debugged with VSCode?